# Perl For looping and scoping variables

Tags: arrays, perl, loops

I'm trying to loop over an array, incrementing by 200. I build a sub-array within that 200, run a calculation on the sub-array, and then move the reading frame to the next set of 200 and repeat. However, whenever I do the second calculation, the new sub-array contains the values of the first sub-array. It's like I can't reset or `undef` the sub-array to re-use it in the next iteration of the `for` loop.

The full code is available on github: https://github.com/bsima/yeast-TRX

To run the code, you'll need the following genome file in the same directory as the script: https://raw.github.com/bsima/yeast-TRX/master/data/bayanus/genome.csv

Here is the relevant code:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use Statistics::Descriptive;

my $species = "bayanus";

open(SPECIES, "<./genome.csv") || die "Cannot open file: $!\n";
my @text = <SPECIES>;

my $geneNameRe  = qr/(eY\w{5}[CW])/;
my $geneRe      = qr/,([atgcATGC-]+)/;

foreach my $line (@text) {
    chomp($line);
    if ( defined $line && $line =~ m/e.{4,},[acgtACGT-]+/ ) {

        my $gene     = match($geneRe,$line);
        my $geneName = match($geneNameRe,$line);

        # Smoothing function
        #
        # This moves through the gene data and counts the position until it arrives
        # at the end of the smoothing window (e.g. 200). Then it calculates the average
        # of the selected data set and outputs it into the respecive `smooth.csv` file 
        # in the following format, to be read later by R's graphing functions:
        #       gene,position,trx.mean,energy.mean
        open(my $smooth, ">>./smooth.csv") || die "Cannot open file $!";
        my $smoothingWindow = 200;
        # Loop through every 200 characters
        for ( my $smoothing = 0; $smoothing < length($gene); $smoothing=$smoothing+$smoothingWindow ) {

            my @trxValues;
            my @energyScores;

            # Loop through every character
            for ( my $position = 0; $position <= $smoothingWindow; $position++ ) {
                my $dinucleotide = substr($gene,$position,2); 

                if ( $dinucleotide =~ m/[actgACTG]{2}/ ) {     
                    my $trxValue = trxScore($dinucleotide);
                    my $energyScore = energyScore($dinucleotide);

                    #print "trxValue = $trxValue\n"; 
                    push @trxValues, $trxValue;
                    push @energyScores, $energyScore;
                }                    
            }

            # Now run the calculations and print to SMOOTH
            my $trxStat = Statistics::Descriptive::Full->new();
            $trxStat->add_data(@trxValues);
            my $trxMean = $trxStat->mean();
            my $energyStat = Statistics::Descriptive::Full->new();
            $energyStat->add_data(@energyScores);
            my $energyMean = $energyStat->mean();

            print "$geneName $smoothing: TRX Values @trxValues\n"; 
            print "$geneName $smoothing: TRX Mean is $trxMean.\n";

            print $smooth $geneName . "," . $smoothing . "," . $trxMean . "," . $energyMean . "\n";

        }
        close $smooth;
    }
}

# This just makes it easy to do regex matches
sub match {
        my ( $re, $text ) = @_;
        if ( $text =~ $re ) {
                return $1;
        }
}

# @name trxScore
# @description Calculates and returns the TRX value of a given phosphate linkage
# @param $dinucleotide {string} The nucleotide to be checked
# @return {integer} The TRX value
sub trxScore {

    my ( $dinucleotide ) = @_;

        my %trxScores = (
            qr/(CG)/ => 43,
            qr/(CA)/ => 42,
            qr/(TG)/ => 42,
            qr/(GG)/ => 42,
            qr/(CC)/ => 42,
            qr/(GC)/ => 25,
            qr/(GA)/ => 22,
            qr/(TC)/ => 22,
            qr/(TA)/ => 14,
            qr/(AG)/ =>  9,
            qr/(CT)/ =>  9,
            qr/(AA)/ =>  5,
            qr/(TT)/ =>  5,
            qr/(AC)/ =>  4,
            qr/(GT)/ =>  4,
            qr/(AT)/ =>  0,
            qr/(.-)/ =>  0,
            qr/(-.)/ =>  0   # These last two are necessary for dealing with missing values in the genomes
        );

    foreach my $re (keys %trxScores) {
        if ( match($re,$dinucleotide) ) {
            return $trxScores{$re};
        } 
    }
    return 0;
}

# @name energyScore
# @description Calculates and returns the delta-E value of a given phosphate linkage
# @param $dinucleotide {string} The nucleotide to be checked
# @return {integer} The delta-E value
sub energyScore {

    my ( $dinucleotide ) = @_;

        my %energyScores = (
            qr/(AA)/ => -18.5,
            qr/(AC)/ => -19.0,
            qr/(AG)/ => -23.6,
            qr/(AU)/ => -15.7,
            qr/(CA)/ => -20.0,
            qr/(CC)/ => -21.4,
            qr/(CG)/ => -26.9,
            qr/(CU)/ => -17.2,
            qr/(GA)/ => -23.7,
            qr/(GC)/ => -22.9,
            qr/(GG)/ => -24.3,
            qr/(GU)/ => -18.9,
            qr/(UA)/ => -19.6,
            qr/(UC)/ => -28.2,
            qr/(UG)/ => -23.3,
            qr/(UU)/ => -15.8,
            qr/(.-)/ =>     0,
            qr/(-.)/ =>     0   # These last two are necessary for dealing with missing values in the genomes
        );

    foreach my $re (keys %energyScores) {
        if ( match($re,$dinucleotide) ) {
            return $energyScores{$re};
        } 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you run the larger script that that code block is a part of, it will print the contents of `@trxValues` to the terminal, and you'll see that the `$smoothing` variable is incrementing properly, so there is nothing wrong with the step portion of the `for` loop, but the contents of `@trxValues` never changes. So, somewhere between the end of the first `for` loop and the beginning of second, the array `@trxValues` doesn't get properly cleared. The same thing happens for `@energyScores`.

Any ideas on this one? I tried using `undef` at the end of the `for` loop, and setting `@trxValues` to zero at the end of the loop, neither of which worked. I'm completely stumped.

**Edit**: changed the code block to be runable by itself.

Comment: You need to show minimal working example, I don't think some one wants to run your code from github

Comment: That's far more than the relevant code. Could you twiddle what you posted down to what's actually relevant? This is the first step in debugging a problem you don't understand, so you should do that in any case!

Comment: What you posted isn't even runnable, which means you must be exceptionally clear, starting with specifying why you think it's not getting cleared. Nothing in what you posted suggests that you even checked.

Comment: Sounds like you need an "inner" array for the 200, which might need be to added to "outer" array; but as @ikegami stated already, we're all guessing at this point.

Comment: I changed the code to be runable by itself. If you run what I posted now, you'll see the problem I'm coming accross

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to always be using the same first smoothing window in your inner for loop.

Try changing:

```
for ( my $position = 0; $position <= $smoothingWindow; $position++ ) {
```

to

```
for ( my $position = $smoothing; $position < $smoothing + $smoothingWindow; $position++ ) {
```

Though the inner loop should be checking against both the smoothing window and `length($gene)` (unless you know it is always an even multiple of 200?)

It also seems odd that you are going up to `length($gene)` one position at a time but your substr is extracting two characters.

Comment: Actually I think this worked.

I'm going up one position at a time but my `substr` is extracting two characters because I need to analyze every pair of characters. If I analyze AGTA I need to analyze AG and GT and TA. If I increment my `for` loop by 2 characters, I'll miss the GT pairing.

Comment: You're intuition was correct. While the script is working properly, I get an error saying `substr outside of string at script.pl line 206`. So it looks like whenever I get to the end of `length($gene)` the `substr` fails and throws the error. I don't know how to fix this off the top of my head - I think I'll have to do some math figuring to adjust the smoothing to be a multiple of the length of the gene. But in any case thanks for the help.

Comment: just make the inner for loop check `$position < $smoothing + $smoothingWindow && $position < length($gene)-1`.  (just noticed its `<=` should have been `<` anyway).  the length check in the outer loop should also be `< length($gene)-1`